# each new terminal shows 0 and tilde

Tags: terminal, conda, zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

simple question that yet does not found an easy answer: each time I open a new terminal, there is always a first line with a 0 and a ~, as in this way:

```bash
0       ~
~ >>
```

I'd like to remove it.
I suspect it's something related with conda, but `auto_activate_base: false` is already present in `~/.condarc`.

Currently I use kitty-term, but it seems terminal independent.
It's however probably related with `zsh`, for which I use `oh-my-zsh` too. [Here](https://github.com/Maik93/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc%23%23default) is my `.zshrc` file.
My full system configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/Maik93/dotfiles), if further setup details are needed.

Comment: Something has set your shell prompt to this, but we don't even know what shell you're using (your dotfiles have startup files for multiple shells).

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention it. I use `zsh`, I've updated the question right now.

Comment: Start with an empty `.zshrc`; that should get rid of the spurious output. Then start adding things back slowly, until you identify which line is responsible for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow just figured it out: in [this line](https://github.com/Maik93/dotfiles/blob/7227110e1822ec51b1e95b0f78167305df7ec129/.zshrc%23%23default#L124) of my zshrc I got a simple `d`, that for oh-my-zsh is an alias for `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh` that prints the current directory...

I leave this here in the unlucky case that someone else faces this issue.